# How do I add buttons using javascript in a bunch of divs generated by Django through loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-templates

I am working on a Django project, where I have made a bunch of HTML divs. I want to add a single button on each div.
[image]

In the image above, I have created a div of class `card-footer` with Django for loop. I want to add a blue coloured like button on each of the divs using javascript but you can see in the image that it is being added into only one div.
Here I am sharing my HTML template.

```html
<div id="posts" class="card">
            <ul class="card-body">
                {% for posts in page_view %}    
                    <li class="card"> 
                         <div class="card-header bg-success">
                            <h5 class="card-title"><a class="text-light" style="text-decoration: none;" href="{% url 'profile' posts.user.id %}">{{ posts.user }}</a></h5> 
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle text-light">{{ posts.timestamp }}</h6>
                         </div>
                        <div class="card-body">

                            <h3 class="card-text">{{ posts.post }}</h3>
                        </div>
                        {% include 'network/like.html' %}
                    </li>
                {% empty %}
                    <h6>No post availabel </h6>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>     
        </div>
```

Here is my `network/like.html`:

```html
<div class="card-footer">
   
    <form action="{% url 'likepost' posts_id=posts.id %}" id="likeform" method="POST" style="display: inline;">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button id = "like" class="btn btn-link" type="submit">Like</button>
    </form>
    <small id="num_of_likes">{{ posts.likepost.all.count }}</small>
    
    {% block script %} 
        <!-- <script>
            let posts_id = "{{ posts.id }}";
        </script> -->
        <script src="{% static 'network/controller.js' %}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
    <button class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration: none;">Comment</button>
    <a href="{% url 'postpage' id=posts.id %}" class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration: none;">View Post</a>
    {% if request.user.id is posts.user.id %}
        <a href="{% url 'editpost' id=posts.id %}" class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration: none;">Edit</a>
       
    {% endif %}
   
</div>
```

In this div of class `card-footer` I want to add a button which contains like in innerHTML but it is being added in only the first one, not the others. Here I am sharing my full js code.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(e){
    // const colon = document.createElement('div');
    // colon.setAttribute('id','colon')
    e.preventDefault()
    const likebtn = document.createElement('button');
    likebtn.setAttribute('class','btn btn-primary');
    likebtn.setAttribute('id','likebtn')
    document.querySelector('.card-footer').appendChild(likebtn);
    document.querySelector('#likebtn').innerHTML = "Like";
    // document.querySelector('.likepost').addEventListener('click', ()=> like_function('likepost'));
})



// let is_like = "{{is_like}}";
// let num_like = "{{num_like}}";

function like_function(likepost){
    document.createElement('button').innerHTML = "Love";
    fetch(`/likepost/${posts_id}`)
    // ,{
    //     method:"POST",
    //     body : JSON.stringify({
    //         "is_like" : is_like,
    //         "num_like" : num_like,
    //     })
    // })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        console.log("Updated.");
        if(result.is_like){
            document.querySelector('#like').innerHTML = "Unike";
        }
        else{
            document.querySelector('#like').innerHTML = "Like";
        }
    })
    location.replace("http://127.0.0.1/")
}

// function like_function(){
//     if (document.querySelector("#like").style.color == "blue"){
//         document.querySelector("#like").style.color = "red";
//     }else{
//         document.querySelector("#like").style.color = "blue";
//     }
// }
```

As I'm new to javascript, I can't figure out what is going wrong! Please let me know if I need to share more information or piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include) the {% include %} tag cannot be used like this (with variables within the template you are going to include.  I'm sure there are ways to accomplish what you want by using JavaScript, or you can just replace the include tag with the entire network/like.html template.

> The include tag should be considered as an implementation of “render
> this subtemplate and include the HTML”, not as “parse this subtemplate
> and include its contents as if it were part of the parent”. This means
> that there is no shared state between included templates – each
> include is a completely independent rendering process.

I haven't tested this, but another possibility would be to create a custom include template tag, as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).